# User upload problem

Tags: php, mysql, upload

i am trying to write a user_upload() function and it works but the image mime type files do not upload but the html files do upload. how can i fix it in this script?

```
function user_upload()
{
    $target_path = "uploads/".$_SESSION['username']."/";
    $client_ID = mysql_query("SELECT 'client_ID'
              FROM 'clients'
              WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
        if(!empty($_FILES)){
            // Add the original filename to our target path.
            // Result is "uploads/filename.extension"
            $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
                if((!$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")
                    ||(!$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/png")
                    ||(!$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") // "jpeg" for Firefox
                    ||(!$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") // "jpeg" for IE
                    ||(!$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "text/css")
                    ||(!$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "text/html")
                    ||(!$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "text/javascript")
                    ||(!$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/msword")
                    ||(!$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
                        &&(!$_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1000000)){
                            echo "The file is not of the right type or size. It should be a
                                    .gif, .png, .jpeg/.jpg, .css, .html, .javascript, .doc, or .pdf and under 1 billion kb.";

                            echo "If you need to send me a file different from these specification, feel free to
                                    email it to me at exaple@support.com. These specifications are for the website's safety.";
                                                              }else{
                                                                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
                                                                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO uploads(ID, URL) VALUES ('$client_ID', '$target_path')");
                                                              } else{
                                                                  echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
                                                              }
                                                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question but `in_array` http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php would be your friend here for that if statement.

Comment: Do *NOT* EVER trust the `['type']` data in the _FILES array. It's userprovided and is trivial to forge. Your code is subject to SQL injection vulnerabilities too.

Comment: @MitMaro - I wouldn't call it unrelated; the more messy the code is, the higher is the chance to err.

Comment: In fact, that's exactly what's happened here.

Answer (score 1):

The if-staement is wrong. Make it `if (((type == png) || (type == gif)) && (size < 1 billion kb)) ...` instead the `!type == png ...`.

Comment: so you are saying do this?  

(($_FILES(type == png))

Comment: @MitMaro: Um, "defiantly?" :)

Comment: That should have been "definitely", will fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't normally do full code audits like this but here are some issue I see with your code. Some are possibly related to the question, some are are other issue I see.

The line `if(!empty($_FILES)){` should be `if(isset($_FILES['uploadedfile'])){`. This is because if someone uploads a file with a different name in the file input your code will still run, throwing multiple errors.

I am uncomfortable with this line:

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

I am 95% positive that basename will make this safe, but I would feel much better if there was a regular expression that white listed the characters that are allowed in the basename. For example:

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
// allow only target paths in the form abc123.ext only
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 -]+\.[a-z0-9]+$/i', $target_path) {
     // invalid data, handle error
}
```

I have two comments on the if statement on the type.

First use [`in_array`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), it will make the code much easier to read and maintain.

Second, there is an error in the if statement the last `||` is tied to the `&&` for the size. This is due to the [order of operations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). You have something like this `a || (b && c)` when you want `(a || b) && c`.

Taking both of these comments I would write your if statemnet as follows.

```
$allowed_types = array("image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "text/css", "text/html", "text/javascript", "application/msword", "application/pdf");
if(!in_array($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"], $allowed_types) || $_FILES["file"]["size"] >= 1000000) {
```

The last thing I would like to mention about your code if the possibity of sql injection. If you use the regular expression above should make the input safe, but because I believe over doing security is never a bad thing I would use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to further sanitize the `$target_path` variable. Like below:

```
$target_path = mysql_real_escape_string($target_path);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO uploads(ID, URL) VALUES ('$client_ID', '$target_path')");
```

I don't know if this will fix any of your problems but these are issues that do need to be fixed in the code and may help in debugging why your code doesn't work.

Comment: the $target_path = mysql_real_escape_string($target_path); fixed my sql injection, in all you answered my question and made the script better.